# Is there a way to extend on classes that have been embedded? (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a assets file that embeds things,

```
[Embed(source='assets.swf', symbol='block')]
public static const SYM_BLOCK:Class;
```

I wish to expand on my block symbols class for later use, so I try to call it a heck of a lot of ways.

EX:

```
package isoscreen 
{
    import assets.Assets;

    public class isoBlock extends SYM_BLOCK
    {
```

...

```
    import assets.Assets.SYM_BLOCK;

    public class isoBlock extends SYM_BLOCK
    {
```

...

```
    import assets.Assets;

    public class isoBlock extends Assets.SYM_BLOCK
    {
```

...

is it possible? I haven't seen any examples of it anywhere.

### ANSWER

The answer was simple, once shown to me. =)

But did require a bit of tinkering.

```
[Embed(source='/assets/assets.swf#block')] // you need to properly change the linkage to the file if your assets are in their own folder (also I found # as a shorthand to get to the symbol inside of the swf)
public class isoBlock extends Sprite
{
    public var top, left, right; //You need to define each symbol within the symbol as well, or it will fail to create.
```

Thank you, folks.

Comment: If your question is: How can I extend a symbol that I created in Flash, you should more clarify that.

Comment: Can't you compile it to .swc and include it in your project? What environment are you using?

Comment: Fiddling with FlashDevelop/Flash CS5 with this one. Making symbols in cs5, coding in flash develop.

Comment: I know how to extend a symbol. I want to know if you can extend a dynamic class that has been embedded. My question is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A symbol is not exactly the same thing as a class, therefore you cannot extend it. You can however, link a symbol to your class, much like you would in Flash authoring.

```
package foo {

    [Embed(source='assets.swf', symbol='block')]

    public class BlockClass extends MovieClip {
        // if your symbol only has one frame, extend Sprite instead
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks grapefrukt. I found the same question answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235342/clone-embedded-swf-class

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this for different reasons. The most important is:

You can't use variables in class declarations. E.g.: `class A extends myVar` is not allowed.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I was hoping maybe there was a little syntax trick out there, like as3 is loaded with. Or maybe I'm to tired to figure out the proper import. But alas. How else might one extend a class of an external swf?

Comment: You should modify the question (or better add a new one or search for an existing one) to: How can I afterwards modify movieclip symbols?

Comment: Quick google search: http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/Flash/Extend_The_MovieClip_Class_To_Create_A_New_Class.htm May this can help you to tweak your symbol with AS3.